# VSTS / TFS - How to track bug browser and version?

Tags: azure-devops

In VSTS and TFS, is there an established way to track browser brand and version for bugs?

We have a team request to add fields for browser type and version, but adding such fields seems to be going down a path in which we'll have fields for many, many things. For example, what about user-agent or browser OS.

Would it be better to use tags or other fields that are more generic that can be used for more than just bugs that are found in browser-based apps?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there have common way to add browser brand/version/type etc information for bug. You can add these information in **System Info** field.

The main functions of **System Info** as:

> Information about the software and system configuration that is
>   relevant to the bug, code review, or feedback.

So it’s unnecessary to add so many customer fields, just use the exist **System Info** field instead.

Comment: And when using the Feedback client or the Test Runner to capture or verify the bug, the browser information and a lot of other details are automatically added by the default diagnostics analyzers.